# Sudo: parted: command not found while executing script to format disk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vmware, sudo

I am trying to create a script to format a newly added disk on a VM in vmware. I want to run the script with a sudouser.

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan
echo "scsi add-single-device 0 0 1 0" > /proc/scsi/scsi
dev=/dev/disk/by-path/*-scsi-0:0:1:0
count=0
while [ ! -r ${dev} ]; do
    count=$(($count+1))
    if [ $count -gt 5 ]; then
        echo "New disk for target is not visible by the OS"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo $count
    sleep 5
done
dev=$(readlink -f $dev) || exit 1
parted -s -- $dev mklabel msdos
```

When I run the script as sudo ./mount.sh, the script fails saying "parted: command not found". I added the path for parted in the PATH variable for the sudouser. What am I missing? Where did I go wrong?

I tried adding sudo to each command individually, then the script fails in the while loop. Do I need to add any more permissions for the sudouser? Or is there any implementation error? Am I missing something? Please help me.

I observed that this happens when I try to run any of the commands in /sbin/
sudo ifconfig throws sudo: ifconfig: command not found

Comment: WARNING! Do not execute this script for testing purposes, your disk could be formatted.

Comment: Im actualy trying to format the disk using a sudouser on a test environment

Comment: Is this script really running non-root? I wouldn't think you'd have permissions to trigger the SCSI bus rescan if you were a regular user, so the earlier lines would fail, and if you're already root you don't need sudo.

Comment: Frankly, I'd kick off the whole script under sudo, and set the PATH you want at its top.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I ran the script as non-root like sudo ./mount.sh. When I run it as ./mount, it says permission denied for SCSI scan, but when I run it as sudo ./mount, it throws error for parted saying command not found.

Comment: I didnt get what you meant by "I'd kick off the whole script under sudo, and set the PATH you want at its top". Can you please elaborate. I shall try this approach

Comment: What you're already doing -- `sudo ./mount.sh` -- means that the entire script **is** running as root, so you don't need to put any sudo commands inside the script. As for the PATH, put something like `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin` at the top of the script, presuming that parted is in one of those directories.

Comment: By the way, don't use filename extensions for scripts -- bash scripts, in particular, aren't compatible with POSIX sh, so a `.sh` extension is inappropriate. See also https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful

Comment: parted is present in /sbin and I have added it to the PATH variable as export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
Wont this help with the PATH issue?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I added "export PATH=$PATH:/sbin" on top of my script as you mentioned and it worked fine.
Is there anyway, I can add this PATH to the sudouser permanently and not set the PATH in each script I want to execute?

Comment: Yes, but that's sudo configuration. Sudo is provided by your operating system, and is not part of bash; there's no way we can know exactly which version of sudo your OS provides and how it works, so read the documentation shipped with your OS (for instance, in `man sudoers`).

By the way, you don't need to use `export` there -- since `PATH` will already be flagged as an environment variable, the export is redundant.

Comment: How can I update the PATH permanently for the sudouser, so that I dont have to set the PATH in each individual script I want to run?